# Android - Animation in series on the same button

Tags: android, animation, sequence

I have a simple application with a few buttons.
At some point, animations are successfully applied to those buttons in a sequence.
Hovewer, in the case all the animated buttons are unique (IE buttons 1,2,3) everything works fine.

On the other hand, if the buttons to animate are repeating (IE 1,1,2,3,2), then the animations  for the same buttons start at the same time even through i uses animation.SetStatOffset with diferend times (by seconds).

```
public void Flash(int delay,int time) {
    Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(),R.anim.gametextbuttonrotation);
    animation.setStartOffset(delay);
    animation.setDuration(time);
    this.startAnimation(animation);
}
```

called by

```
private void Flash(List<Integer> sequence)
{
    int i=0;
    int COOLDOWN=1000;
    for (Integer integer : sequence) {
        buttons[integer].Flash(i++*COOLDOWN,COOLDOWN/2);    
    }

}
```

I tried to read cod/google but to no help.

OK, if anyone tries to do this heres the solution:

1) create a local variable of AnimationSet in the View Class
2) when starting a new sequence, initialize the AnimationSet by using constructor (AFAIK there is no such thing as AnimationSet.empty().....
3) inside foreach loop, create the animations and then play them

```
private void flash(List<Integer> sequence)
{
    int i=0;
    int COOLDOWN=1000;
    for(Button button : buttons)
    {
       button.clearAnimation(); 
       button.animSet=new AnimationSet(); //is inside a private method, here All-in-1 to be simple
    }



    for (Integer integer : sequence) {
        buttons[integer].addFlash(i++*COOLDOWN,COOLDOWN/2); 
    }

    for (Integer integer : sequence) {
        buttons[integer].flash();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is weird but after posting this i got a relevation :D

I first thought, that startAnimation(...) was adding animations to an button allowing for more then 1, but it seems it rewrites them....

Solution:

added to the class
     
    AnimationSet animSet; 
.
.
.

  Animation animation=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(),R.anim.gametextbuttonrotation);
  animation.setStartOffset(delay);
  animation.setDuration(time);
  animSet.addAnimation(animation);
  this.startAnimation(animSet);

Comment: And I'd written you a nice little explanation as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking about it. If you set two animations on a view the second one will just override the first one. Therefore the animations 'aren't starting at the same time' only the second (with delay) is running. You cannot tell that they are running at the same time as the animation is the same, perhaps you should toggle the animation to test your bug further:

```
 // XXX Debug code remember to remove
 boolean toggle = true;
 public void Flash(int delay,int time) {
         int animId = toggle ? R.anim.gametextbuttonrotation : R.anim.another_animation;
         toggle = !toggle;    

         Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(), animId); 
         .....
 }
```

In this scenario every second animation will be different.

If you want to run two animations on one view you should look at using an animation set.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html

On a side not there is another way to show an animation:

```
     public void flash(int delay,int time) {
         Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this.getContext(),R.anim.gametextbuttonrotation); 
         animation.setDuration(time);
         animation.setStartTime(delay);             
         this.setAnimation(animation);
     }
```

P.S.
[Java naming conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) recommend starting your method names with a lowercase letter.